# remove special character from string in snowpipe copy command in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

Im trying to load data to snowflake table which is having numeric datatypes but the column value contains number with special character `0,0000` due to this copy command is failing. Is their any chance we can handle this in file format instead of handling this in select statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no option in file format that would handle strings inside of a numeric field.  This is the purpose of allowing you to use a SELECT statement in your COPY INTO command to handle simple manipulation.

Your other option would be to load it as a string/varchar during your COPY INTO command, and then handle the casting as a secondary step in your processing.  This would likely be faster processing, actually.